# sanitize untrusted input for templates

Tags: javascript, security, html5

Attempting to populate HTML string-templates from untrusted input.

```
function sanitizer(str, i, list){
        return str + (this[i] ?? '').toString()
        .replace(/&/g, '&#x26;')
        .replace(/</g, '&#x3C;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&#x3E;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&#x27;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&#x22;')
        ;
}
function sanitize(str, ...input){
        return str.map(sanitizer, input).join('');
}
function template(data){
        return sanitize`<div>${ data }</div>`;
}
```

ref: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#Output_Encoding_Rules_Summary

Calling `template('1<23')` should render a HTMLDivElement with Text '1﹤23'.

notable development since posting:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sanitizer
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Sanitizer_API

previously this substituted for look-alike characters which works well generally, except for copy+paste, in which case a convert-back would solve for, and potentially avoids double-escaping/encoding problems:

```
function sanitizer(str, i, list){
        return str + (this[i] ?? '').toString()
        .replace(/&/g, '＆')
        .replace(/</g, '﹤')
        .replace(/>/g, '﹥')
        .replace(/'/g, '’')
        .replace(/"/g, '”')
        .replace(/\//g, '／')
        ;
}
```

Comment: by replacing characters with similar characters, are you inadvertantly causing people issues with copy-pasting legitimate content?

Comment: @TKoL helpful comment, thanks very much. In this case I don't see this as an issue simply because the objective (at this point in the view lifecycle) is to ensure if the backend services miss proper encodings or the template doesn't handle the specific scenario this sanitization will address them to prevent security problems/xss at that point. I'm simply attempting to provide an as simple as possible general solution for frontend templates.

Comment: personally, I would rather rely on a known and used library for sanitization than hoping that i've thought of everything...

Comment: @TKoL thanks, I understand and recognize that's a common perspective (to use libraries). I'd prefer to know and understand the fundamentals myself, especially critical ones, rather than pass the responsibility and trust to someone else. All things considered this of course would require comprehensive testing to prove it works.

Comment: @TKoL in the more general case where more feature are needed I would simply use a library (ie LitElement, lit-html) for this, however in a lightweight implementation for minor applications that I have I want to know there is a reasonable approach toward a solution (this case).

Comment: Just a quick note that [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) already does escaping.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 6 → 5. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## approach

You are striking out in your own direction,
preferring custom code over an upstream library
that's been battle tested by a large community.

This can be made to work.
But using a supported library with a good track record
would instill greater confidence that the
real-world security goals have been achieved.

## security

Do these functions correctly implement the cited
[OWASP advice](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#output-encoding-for-html-contexts)?
Yes, they do.

Presenting unit tests with the code would
yield a stronger security argument, and
automated browser-specific Selenium system tests
would be stronger still.

This code attempts to alter DOM semantics
without altering the rendered appearance.
If you have use cases that could tolerate some
corruption of user-supplied text,
such as deliberately deleting certain characters,
then again we would have a stronger security argument.
Why would this be of interest?
I can imagine future browser bugs where double rendering
manages to undo your `sanitizer` transformation.

Consider simplifying the `sanitizer` signature
so it just accepts a single string,
putting responsibility for catenating strings on the caller.
In software engineering, simplicity is a virtue.
Doubly so for security-critical code.

## performance

`sanitizer()` processes a string of arbitrary length,
and makes half a dozen scans of the string,
looking for half a dozen dangerous characters.
This works.

Rather than making repeated scans,
consider making just a single scan where you examine each character,
and append it or its sanitized substitute to an output string.